# Pass queryset to overridden django admin template

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible for me to pass the results of a queryset to the `change_list.html` when I'm overriding it?

For example: 
I've overridden the admin template for change_list and want to add a dropdown in the list view where it shows all available users from the `User` model.

Queryset

```
users = User.objects.all()
{'user': users} #something along the lines of rendering this to change_list.html
```

change_list.html

```
{% for u in users %}
    {{ u.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hm. I think we need some more information. Do you override only the template or also the admin class? Do you have a more explicit code example?

Comment: @Norman8054 not really. I've not written any code yet for this. Was just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. (Everything is possible.) Try to override the admin class to transmit your queryset to the overridden template.

Comment: This answer would need some explanation or at least some example to be useful.